# Forming a new dataframe from the old data frame using for-loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

My data frame "c1"

```
 steps interval
   <dbl>    <int>
 1     0        0
 2     0        5
 3     0       10
 4     0       15
 5     0       20
 6     0       25
 7     0       30
 8     0       35
 9     0       40
10     0       45
# ... with 278 more rows

PS: Sorry for providing only a small sample from data
```

I want to create a new data frame 'c11' by adding the rows of "interval" column for every interval of 50, such that the sum of every 50 steps(column steps) is calculated accordingly.

My new data frame should look like

```
 steps interval
   <dbl>    <int>
 1     0        0
 2     0        50
 3     0       100
 4     10      150
 5     0       200
 6     6       250
 7     20      300
 8     0       350
 9     230     400
10     0       450
```

My code

```
n=0
j=0
y <- nrow(c1)/50
class(n)
c11 <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = y, ncol = 2)) 

class(c11)
for (i in 1:nrow(c1)) {
  n <- n + c1[i,1]
  if (i%%50==0)
  {
    c11[j,1]<- i
    c11[j,2] <- n
    j <- j+1
    n = 0
  }

}
```

Can someone correct the code as it shows up the wrong output?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Please try and explain it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `cut` in `aggregate`

```
with(c1, aggregate(list(steps = steps), 
     list(interval = cut(interval, c(seq(min(interval), max(interval), 50), Inf), 
     labels = seq(min(interval), max(interval), 50), include.lowest = TRUE)), sum))
```

To make it more explicit, we can separate the steps

```
c1$group <- cut(c1$interval, c(seq(min(c1$interval), max(c1$interval), 50), Inf),
      labels = seq(min(c1$interval), max(c1$interval), 50), include.lowest = TRUE)

aggregate(steps~group, c1, sum)
```

Comment: @AnanyaVidyanathan Can you explain what do you mean by `not working` ? did you get any error message or wrong answer? Also I had one typo in my earlier version. I have corrected it now. Can you try again ?

Comment: Error: in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate

Comment: @AnanyaVidyanathan I created a new column with `cut`. Can you try that now and let me know.

Comment: Yea @Ronak Shah it's working perfectly....Thanks, man.... btw would mind finding what is wrong in my code?

Comment: @AnanyaVidyanathan The one main thing I could see you are iterating over every row which doesn't look correct as you want to `sum` every 50 `interval` and not rows. Also usually, in R most of the times you could get away without using loops using functions like `aggregate`/`dplyr`